# Tabla con filas desplazables - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lista, tablas

Estoy intentando hacer en android una tabla en la que yo pueda seleccionar una fila, arrastrarla hasta una posición de la tabla y cuando la suelte, esa fila se quede en la posición que le he indicado. un ejemplo seria:

1.
2.
3.
4.

Selecciono y arrastro el 4 a la posición entre el 1 y el 2 y que se quede de la siguiente forma:

1.
4.
2.
3.

PD: no sé si de no poderse hacer con una tabla si hubiese alguna otra forma de hacerlo.

Muchas gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Comment: Que llevas hecho?

Comment: Actualmente no llevo nada, estoy haciendo un documento técnico recogiendo las cosas que quiero que haga la aplicación y como tendría que hacerlo.

Comment: Munir74, bienvenido a SOes. Muy dificilmente podras obtener una respuesta si no presentas el codigo que has intentado. Considera leer el articulo [ask] y despues [edit] tu publicacion e incluir un [mcve].